# display:none not correctly working on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media, display

there ho here's a `CSS` code, I want to hide it on PC view but visible on Phone view, I'm able to achieve my results on PC, but not on Phone, because `display: none;` is interfering with the code's work. Can anyone please check it?

```
  /* --------- Game-section-mobile---------*/

* {
  transition: all .155s ease-in-out;
}

.event-link {
  margin: 300px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.event-h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.events {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: none;
}

.events .shadowbox {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.event {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.event  .event-h3 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.event {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.event:hover {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.events .shadowbox:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
}

.event .event-h3,
.event p {
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.event:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.shadowbox img{
  margin-top: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 775px) {
  .event:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .event:hover {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .event:nth-of-type(1) {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .event {
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }

  .shadowbox img{
    margin-top: 50%;
    height: 150px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 775px){
  .events{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a second media query for .events. So when your screen width is smaller than 775px, your .events will get displayed again. Which is the case on a mobile view. Delete or comment it out, and it should work.

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 775px){
  .events{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this :)
I defined another class and shifted all of them in that class, It's working now